# regex javascript doesn't return parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

When I am trying to do my regex in js:

```html
var matc = source.match(/sometext(\d+)/g);
```

The result I get is "sometext5615", "sometext5616"...etc
But what I want: is to get "5615", "5616"...etc

Do you have any idea how to get only what is inside the parenthese ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a "match all" for global matches, so you cannot use `g` in this context and also have capture groups.  The simplest solution would be to remove the `g` and then just use `matc[1]` to get 5615, etc.

If you need to match multiple of these within the same string then your best bet would be to do a ["search and don't replace"](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/)

```
var matc = [];
source.replace(/sometext(\d+)/g, function (_, num) {
    matc.push(num);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[`String.prototype.match`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) has two different behaviors:

- If the regex doesn't have the global `g` flag, it returns `regex.exec(str)`. That means that, if there is a match, you will get an array where the `0` key is the match, the key `1` is the first capture group, the `2` key is the second capture group, and so on.
- If the regex has the global `g` flag, it returns am array with all matches, but without the capturing groups.

Therefore, if you didn't use the global flag `g`, you could use the following to get the first capture group

```
var matc = (source.match(/sometext(\d+)/) || [])[1];
```

However, since you use the global flag, you must iterate all matches manually:

```
var rg = /sometext(\d+)/g,
    match;
while(match = rg.exec(source)) {
    match[1]; // Do something with it, e.g. push it to an array
}
```